# Gregar Campos en Automatico al dar clic en voton [+] o eliminar campos a dar clic en boton [-]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hola a todos estoy buscando la forma de agregar o eliminar una linea de campos. tengo 8 campos y quiero ver la forma de agregar una linea igual al dar clic en el botón agregar.

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="php/GuardarPersonal.php" method="POST" novalidate>
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">  
                          <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Campos</button>
                          <div id="items">
                                        <label for="sel1">N0. Empreado:</label>
                                    <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="input[]" placeholder="# Empreado"></div>
                                    </div>
                          <div id="items">
                              <label for="sel1">Fecha:</label>
                              <div><input type="date" class="form-control" name="input[]"></div>
                                    </div>
                          <div id="items">
                                <label for="sel1">Area:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="input[]">
                                <option>1.- Vacaciones</option>
                                <option>2.- Tiempo X Tiempo</option>
                                <option>3.- Permiso Falta</option>
                                <option>3.- Horario Diferente de Trabajo</option>
                                </select>
                          </div>
                           <div id="items">
                                <label for="sel1">Hora Inicio:</label>
                               <div><input type="time" class="form-control" name="input[]" ></div>
                                    </div>
                           <div id="items">
                               <label for="sel1">Hora Fin:</label>
                               <div><input type="time" class="form-control" name="input[]"></div>
                                    </div>
                          <div id="items">
                              <label for="sel1">Causa Tiempo Extra:</label>
                                    <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="input[]" placeholder="Causa"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="items">
                              <label for="sel1">Solicitante:</label>
                                    <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="input[]" placeholder="Solicita"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="items">
                              <label for="sel1">Autoriza:</label>
                                    <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="input[]" placeholder="Solicita"></div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
          </br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Solicitud</button>
</form>
```

Comment: puedes usar `append` de jquery, con eso podrias agregar campos utilizando el evento click